# Time series in grouped dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

I am currently dealing with multiple time series within a grouped/nested dataframe and I do not know how to proceed. I hope that someone here can help me on this matter.

My dataset consist of 5 grouping variables (`Category`), each of which contains 10 replicates (`ID`). Each of this replicate consists in 60 consecutive observations at regular time intervals (`Time`). Each of this observations then consists of multiple variables: `Amount`, `Walk_1`, `Walk_2` and `Walk_1+2`. However, I also have three other variables (`Amount1`, `Amount2`, `Amount3`) which consist in the `Number` variable splitted by area.

So, to have it graphically:

A { (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) { 1(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 60); 2(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 60); ..and so on.

B { (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20) { 11(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 60); 12(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 60); ..and so on.

.

.

E { (41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50) { 41(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 60); 42(1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 60); ..and so on.

What I want to know is whether the variables `walk_1`, `walk_2` and `walk_1+2`:

- Differ within and across the grouping variables `Category` or `ID`
- show an oscillatory/periodic trend over the 60 observations.

I tried to nest the dataset into `ID` categories, then apply the `acf` function by group using the `mutate` + `map` function. This way, I obtain a series of acf values. However, I do not know how to proceed for visualising and analysing the dataset.

Is this method functional to my purpose, or should I use a different function?

EDIT: Since I was asked to put a reproducible example, here is some similar data structure with a simplified fake dataset.

```
dat1 = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 1:5, each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:50,each=60)),
walk_1 = rnorm(n = 3000,mean = 10,sd = 4),
walk_2 = rnorm(n = 3000, mean = 5, sd = 5),
amount = sample.int(50, 3000, replace = TRUE))

dat1 <- dat1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(walk_12 = walk_1 + walk_2) %>%
  nest() 

dat1 <- dat1 %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, 
                   ~ mutate(., Time = seq(1, 60, by = 1)))) %>%
  unnest() 
  
dat1 <- dat1 %>%
   mutate(walk_1 = ifelse(Time == 1, NA, walk_1)) %>%
   mutate(walk_2 = ifelse(Time == 1, NA, walk_2)) %>%
   mutate(walk_12 = ifelse(Time == 1, NA, walk_12))
```

And here's the output of dput(head(dat1)):

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), category = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), walk_1 = c(NA, 7.93428744179875, 11.6326574689602, 
10.3687325793843, 6.2631358473095, 14.0134490135895), walk_2 = c(NA, 
-4.03741066457775, 2.91290193315445, 8.04203547142631, 9.42608080771425, 
16.2253066800552), amount = c(34L, 37L, 31L, 26L, 29L, 33L), 
    walk_12 = c(NA, 3.896876777221, 14.5455594021146, 18.4107680508106, 
    15.6892166550237, 30.2387556936447), Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(ID = 1L, 
    .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

@Marco Here, `amount` is a count of individuals and thus previous measurements within the same `ID` should not be independent. `Amount1`, `Amount2` and `Amount3` are correlated in the sense that `Amount1` + `Amount2` + `Amount3` = `amount`.

What I need to do is to understand whether `walk_1`, `walk_2` and (consequently) `walk_1+2` have periodicity and, if tha is the case, whether this periodicity is equal among different `ID` within or across the different `Category`. Also, I do not have data for any first time point in each `ID`, so the time series to analyse is 59 points.

I hope that this clarify my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question and give a reproducible example - particularly giving the output of ``dput( head(dat))`` in your answer.

Comment: what periodicity are you talking about? weekly, monthly ...? because you said, you have time data. or just some arbitrary periodicity?  like 25.8 minutes?

Comment: @marco My time series starts 00:00:00 and goes up to 09:50:00. It is a POSIXct object and increases at 10 minutes intervals. I need to explore this time series to see whether there is a periodicity, I do not know the time intervals between peaks (if any)

Answer (score 0):

For comparing statistics between categories and IDs use dplyr.
The time series analysis is not trivial to do and with only 60 time points, it is not easy to find meaningful periodics. Anyway, I have good experience doing this with prophet. Please give an example on how AmountX,Y,Z is plays a role. It is unclear for me.

```
#example data
dat = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 1:5,each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:10,each=60),5),
time = as.POSIXct(rep(rep(1:60,10),5)*100000,origin="1970-01-01"), # time frame 2 month + a little
walk_1 = rnorm(n = 3000,mean = 10,sd = 4)
)
##to analyse between categories or ID usw group_by from the dplyr package
dat %>% group_by(category) %>% summarise(sddev = sd(walk_1))
#or some other interesting statistics besides standard deviation

dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(sddev = sd(walk_1)) # to compare repliactes
dat %>% group_by(category, ID) %>% summarise(sddev = sd(walk_1)) # to compare repliactes and categories

#to investigate for periodic trends is not that trivial. i love to use prohpet for this https://facebook.github.io/prophet/

library(prophet)
#make a time series analysis for category 1 and replicate 1
a = dat %>% filter(category==1,ID==1) %>% mutate(ds =  time,y=walk_1) %>% select(-walk_1,-time) %>% prophet()
future <- make_future_dataframe(a, periods = 365)
b =  predict(a, future)
b$trend # the long term trend
b$weekly # weekly trend
#a plot of trends
prophet_plot_components(m, b) 
    #please note I use random data,
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your answer. So you think my dataset is limited in the number of data points? My question is, how can I find the significance of the periodic trends through prophet? 
Please see my edited question for more detail.